# Debian Squeeze 64-bit ssh cant connect and libssl error

Tags: debian-squeeze, logging

I cant login on ssh in the VM i leaved the one that was prev connected open but i cant connect via new connection also when i try to apt-get i get this error:

```
/usr/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Please help me :/
Thanks in advance
Also i did this previously and deleted the symbolic links

```
ln -sf /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 ln -sf
/usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

Comment: A) where did you get the idea that you could do this? B) After you deleted the 0.9.8 symbolic links, did you put the original library back?

Comment: next time youre up for an adventure, try deleting libpam.0.so

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need to reinstall the old libraries somehow, either by finding the SSL package online (like [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/amd64/libssl0.9.8/download)) and downloading it to the server somehow (good luck with that), then running

```
dpkg -i libssl0.9.8_0.9.8o-4squeeze13_amd64.deb
```

to install the package again.